# Please direct me to https through hot network questions if I am browsing securely

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions, ssl

I noticed that the Stack Exchange sites are now browse-able in [https](https://stackoverflow.com/) [mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). All the links from the top-bar are also linked as `//someplace.stackexchange.com` etc.

But, this is not the case for the [**Hot Network Questions**](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) section in the sidebar. While the heading itself is linked as `//stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot`, the listed questions are hard bound to *`http`* addresses.

Can this be fixed and made consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now, probably as part of the efforts in [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232).

[image]