# Make share links HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ssl, share-this

I've been using Stack Exchange (specifically Stack Overflow) on HTTPS for a while now. You should too.

[image]

Either:

- Make the share link produce HTTPS every time.

  ```
  .-------------------------------------------.
  | User is browsing on | share link produces |`.
  |---------------------|---------------------| |
  | http://st...        | https://st...       | |
  | https://st...       | https://st...       | |
  `-------------------------------------------`.|
    `-------------------------------------------`
  ```
- Have it on HTTP when browsing in HTTP and HTTPS when browsing with HTTPS.

  ```
  .-------------------------------------------.
  | User is browsing on | share link produces |`.
  |---------------------|---------------------| |
  | http://st...        | http://st...        | |
  | https://st...       | https://st...       | |
  `-------------------------------------------`.|
    `-------------------------------------------`
  ```

And while you're at it [Make chat onebox HTTPS links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111493/make-chat-onebox-https-links) and [Please direct me to https through hot network questions if I am browsing securely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232259/please-direct-me-to-https-through-hot-network-questions-if-i-am-browsing-securel)

Comment: It's probably time to revisit this. Now that the conversion is official, I found that [96% of new posts end up containing HTTP links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292609), with a lot of them presumably due to sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS is not supported officially yet, it works to some extent, but it also breaks in a lot of situations. Changing the shared link to a version that breaks often is a very bad idea, this change should be the last step in the move to SSL once everthing works fine.

Comment: My experience so far when browsing SE sites on HTTP is quite good. Though I think it owes in part to the HTTPS Everywhere extension I am using which as I see now is not HTTPSing some requests. My feature request isn't such a big deal, though I really hope of more news of improvements in HTTPS support. :-)

Comment: @MarkGarcia - from what I understand the biggest problem isn't technical, but logistical/financial. The current url scheme for child metas (`http://meta.*.stackexchange.com`) breaks the rules surrounding wildcards in security certificates so SE has to either buy 100's of security certificates or change the meta url. (Hint: It's going to be the latter - which is quite a logistical nightmare).

Comment: Stupid question, but what do we gain with using SSL all the time? I mean, I don't mind if people see the results of whatever I type into the text boxes here...

Comment: @Mr Lister One of the things that gets sent in plain text is the cookie your browser's using to authenticate. You probably don't want people seeing that. See, e.g., http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep . I also think someone like, say, a mod would really rather not have everything they do on a site be plain text, since it might include private information in responses.

Comment: Kind of shocked that SO isn't officially on SSL yet. I use HTTPS Everywhere and SO has worked perfectly (on HTTPS) for years.

Comment: Surely, this should be fixed now, right? I've been editing share links to use https before I post them for a while now and never ran into any problems.

Answer (score 2):

All Q&A sites are now HTTPS and all share links are rendering as HTTPS. Enjoy!