# Make share links HTTPS for all sites where HTTPS is fully supported

Tags: feature-request, ssl, share-this

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238192/make-share-links-https), the "share" URL is HTTP not HTTPS because HTTPS "is not fully supported". However, this question is 2 years old and I strongly suspect that HTTPS has close to full support at this point, at least on all the main sites.

Is it possible to either:

1. Use HTTPS share links when a given site has HTTPS support.
2. Failing that, use HTTPS links when you are currently on the HTTPS version of the page.
3. As an alternative to #2, could there be an account setting to enable a "beta" HTTPS link?

I feel like a real chump when I go to share a link and it's http, given that I silently judge people who send me http links that my HTTP Everywhere upgrades to HTTPS.

Comment: "I strongly suspect that HTTPS has close to full support at this point, at least on all the main sites". It is still work in progress. We are much closer to it than 2 years ago, but still lots of work to do.

Comment: You want to share a link that might be broken? That's not a good idea I guess.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, I *only* navigate on HTTPS myself, so presumably I will see if the page is broken when I'm on it. Plus, right now I manually change all HTTP links to HTTPS before sharing them anyway and it's never bit me before. Even if there were a 1% chance that the link is broken for someone else and not me, I don't mind going, "Oh, a certificate error? Maybe try the HTTP version." when they say, "I'm not seeing anything at that link."

Comment: Workaround: instead of left-clicking "share" and copying, __right-click__ it (or whatever on Mac) and copy the link. It will be https if you are on https page.